# MySQL select and sum from multiple table without duplicate it

Tags: mysql, sum

i have 3 tables :

```
table1

code(Primary key) | name | quantity

B001 | sand | 50

B002 | nail | 100

B003 | paint | 10
```

=======

```
table2

code | qty_out

B001 | 2

B001 | 1

B001 | 20

B002 | 10

B002 | 30
```

=======

```
table3

code  | qty_in

B001   | 1

B001   | 5

B002   | 5

B002  | 10
```

=======

Result that I want is:

```
table1

code  | name    | quantity  | Out      | In      | total

B001  | sand    | 50        | 23       | 6       | 33

B002  | nail    | 100       | 40       | 15     |  75

B003  | paint   | 10        | null/0  |  null/0  | 10
```

I used this query :

```
SELECT table1.code, table1.name, table1.quantity, sum(table2.qty_out ) AS 'Out', sum( table3.qty_in ) AS 'In'
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.code = table1.code
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.code = table1.code
GROUP BY table1.code
ORDER BY table1.code ASC
```

In that query I get result like this...code B001 out 46 and in 18, code B002 out 80 and in 30, code B003 out null and in null

How to fix this?

Comment: Use `left outer join` so you will get an result for B003. For the other wrong result, try a `select * from` ... to see what the result of the query is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query

```
select t.code,t.name,t.quantity,t.out,t.in,(t.out+t.in) as total
from ( 
      SELECT table1.code, table1.name, table1.quantity,
                ( select sum(table2.qty_out) 
                  from table2 
                  where table1.code=table2.code ) as out,
                ( select sum(table3.qty_in) 
                  from table3
                  where table3.code=table1.code ) as in  
      FROM table1
     ) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery, a `UNION` clause and `GROUP`ping, I built the following query :

```
SELECT
  p.code,
  p.name,
  -- Using IFNULL to handle products without stock variation
  IFNULL(SUM(q.q_in), 0) AS total_in,
  IFNULL(SUM(q.q_out), 0) AS total_out,
  -- Compute the new stock level
  p.qty + IFNULL(SUM(q.q_in), 0) - IFNULL(SUM(q.q_out), 0) AS qty
FROM (
  -- UNION (= concatenate) prod_in and prod_out tables
  SELECT
    product,
    qty AS q_in,
    0 AS q_out    -- Enforce schema (otherwise, q_out is dropped)
  FROM prod_in 
  UNION
  SELECT
    product,
    0 AS q_in,
    qty AS q_out
  FROM prod_out
) AS q
-- Using a RIGHT join to show products without stock variations
RIGHT JOIN products AS p
  ON p.code = q.product
-- Group by id to get the summarized view
GROUP BY q.product
```

Here's the query in a [working SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c62ff/20/0) with your sample data